# Promise Rejection Error.Location should be an object with latitude and longitude

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

When i try consoling the location in getCurrentLocation() it returns valid latitude and longitude,however,it isn't passed on to the lat and lon as i received undefined for both during first render.As soon as I re-tap the button it works fine, both lat and lon get valid values .So can anyone help about why it isn't giving correct output during first render?

```
    const [lat, setLat] = useState();
        
    const [lon, setLon] = useState();
    
    const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState(null);
    
    const [address, setAddress] = useState("");
     useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      let { status } = await Location.requestPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== "granted") {
        setErrorMsg("Permission to access location was denied");
      }
    })();
  });

  

    const getLocationFromCoords = async () => {
        let address = await Location.reverseGeocodeAsync({
          latitude: lat,
          longitude: lon,
        });
        setAddress(
          `${address[0].name},${address[0].street},${address[0].city},${address[0].postalCode}`
        );
      };

  const getCurrentLocation = async () => {
    let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({
      accuracy: Location.Accuracy.Highest,
      timeout: 1000,
    });
    setLocation(location);
    console.log(location);

    if (errorMsg) {
      return;
    }
    const { coords } = location;
    setLat(coords.latitude);
    setLon(coords.longitude);
    console.log(lat, lon);
    getLocationFromCoords();
  };

  const getLocationFromAddress = async () => {
    let location = await Location.geocodeAsync(address);
    setLat(location[0].latitude);
    setLon(location[0].longitude);
  };

    return (  <View
        style={{
          flexDirection: "row",
          marginRight: 23,
          position: "relative",
        }}
      >
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          onChangeText={(text) => setAddress(text)}
          placeholder="Name,Street name,City"
          value={address}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => getCurrentLocation()}>
          <MaterialIcons
            name="my-location"
            size={24}
            color="black"
            style={{
              borderBottomWidth: 1,
              paddingTop: 5,
              paddingBottom: 2,
              borderBottomColor: "#888",
            }}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>)
```